# Can Mathematica solve Kuhn-Tucker Equations with arbitrary functional form (up to 2nd order derivative)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic, inequalities

I am in a business of solving a 5-variables optimization with inequality constraints, and I would like to maintain the functional form as arbitrary as possible. So far, I am assuming that the objective $b$ is 2nd order differentiable, with $b' > 0$ and $b'' < 0$, over a support of $R_+^5$.

(The problem is based on game-theoretic setting, where the goal is to solve for a system of 5 first order conditions derived from KKT.)

Would Mathematica possibly solve this problem **symbolically**? I have solved by hand a 4 variables case, exhausting 16 cases from the Complimentary-Slackness conditions.

Here goes the set of equations that I have solved by hand:

First order condition solves to be:

> $\begin{array}[]
>     \frac{\partial U_1}/{\partial e_1} & = (1 - \alpha ) b'( e_1 + e_2 + e_3 + e_4)
>     + \alpha b' ( e _ 1 +  e _ 2) - (1 - \alpha ) c \\
>     \frac{\partial U_2}{\partial e_2} & = (1 - \alpha ) b'( e _ 1 +  e _ 2)
>     + \alpha b' ( e_1 + e_2 + e_3 + e_4) - (1 - \alpha ) c \\
>     \frac{\partial U_3}{\partial e_3} & = (1 - \beta ) b' ( e_3 +  e_1 ) -
>     (1-\beta) c\\
>     \frac{\partial U_4}{\partial e_4} & = (1 - \beta ) b' ( e_4 +  e_1 ) -
>     (1-\beta) c\\
> \end{array}$

By the Complimentary-Slackness condition, $\forall i = \{ 1,2,3,4\}$, for $e_i
\ge 0$,
$\frac{\partial U_i}{\partial e_i} \le 0$, and
$\frac{\partial U_i}{ \partial U_i }\times e _ i  = 0$.

Thank you!

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing more about the equations.

Comment: Have updated the question with a question that I have solved by hand (yet, typesetting systems of equation on this Forum does not come natural to me. So, bear with me on this.) Thank you!